What is the best way to make a coroutin an awaitable type?
Let task foo() be a coroutine. I want to support:
co_await foo()

What would be the best way to do it?

Implement task::promise_type::await_transform that return an Awaiter.
Implement Awaiter final_suspend() in task::promise_type, like Lewis Baker code here: https://godbolt.org/z/3qKqWEqYG
Implement a global operator co_await(task&& t)
Implement operator co_await() in task

Any thoughts, knowledge, or practice on the mater?

The type of the function (coroutine) that contains the line co_await foo() is important. What context do you want this line to work in, and what do you want it to do?

Note that the second bullet point doesn't actually make the task awaitable. It's just one possible strategy of dealing with continuations. The way the linked code makes the task awaitable is by implementing operator co_await (your 4th bullet point).

@Wutz; I don't see where it implements operator co_await. It just implements an awaitable interface.

@NicolBolas line 96: awaiter operator co_await() && noexcept

None of the options you've listed are ways to create an awaitable type.
operator co_await is for when you want to force some type that you don't control to become awaitable. await_transform is for when the promise wants to convert an object it doesn't control to become an awaitable (or otherwise engage with awaitables).
Since you wrote task and can write it however you like, you can just implement the awaitable interfaces on the type: await_ready, await_suspend, and await_resume as public non-static members.
Within the implementation of these functions, you need to have a way to store the coroutine handle you're given and resume it when your current process is finished. But that depends on what's going on inside of task.

Another case for operator co_await is if you don't want your type to be its own awaiter. For example there may be extra machinery needed for awaiting but which is not needed in the object itself. Or you may need a stateful awaiter, and you also want to allow your object to be awaited by multiple people simultaneously.

Thanks! What about this option implemented by Lewis Baker: godbolt.org/z/1nW9escTs, so the final_awaiter is for the co_await promise.final_suspend(). Is this a good practice for some use cases?

@dwto: That has nothing to do with what you asked. It's useful; it helps with chaining coroutines together as it allows you to talk to a future to a finished coroutine. But that is not what makes a type awaitable, which is what you asked about.
